# How can I query Elasticsearch to output the exact position of a searched keyword or sentence?

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed several documents into my Elasticsearch cluster and queried the Elasticsearch cluster using some keywords and sentences, the output from my query displayed the entire documents where the sentences or keywords where be found.

I want a case where if a query is carried out, it should display just the paragraph where the sentence or keyword can be found and also show the page number it was found.

Comment: did you check highlighting functionality of elasticsearch.. which will generate snippets based on where your query is maching.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but the entire document was displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) functionality with [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-fields.html#source-filtering). So it will show only field which is required and you can hide the remaining field.

You can set `_source` to `false` so it will return only highlighted field. If you want to search on different field and highlight on different field then you can set `require_field_match` to `false`. Please refer the elastic doc for more referance.

```json
GET /_search
{
  "_source":false,
  "query": {
    "match": { "content": "kimchy" }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match":false,
    "fields": {
      "content": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of displaying an entire paragraph ending with a full stop where the search keyword is found without cutting the display result in between the words.